# Can we run TestNG test cases via bat file on a independent machine? (machine which does not have the Eclipse project of the test being run)

Tags: selenium-webdriver, testng, testng-eclipse

I want to create a .bat file to run my TestNG test cases. I should be able to transfer the file to any computer and execute the test cases.

Is it possible to do the above in any way. If yes how?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

See [4 - Running TestNG](http://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html#running-testng) on TestNG's [documentation page](http://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html). There you will find information on how to run TestNG from the command line (the same commands can be used in a [batch file](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Batch_file)).

Note that batch files are specific to Windows. If you want to be able to run this on any platform that supports Java and TestNG then I recommend that instead of a batch file you [run TestNG programmatically](http://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html#running-testng-programmatically) from Java.